# Can't run unit tests on smart device emulator

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, windows-ce

I'm running Visual Studio 2008 and have a C# program that runs beautifully on the "Pocket PC 2003 Second Edition" emulator.  However, when I try to run any unit tests I get an error on the first test:

```
The test adapter  ('Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAdapter,
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.Adapter, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a') required to execute this test could not be loaded.
Check that the test adapter is installed properly.
ActiveSync bootstrap initialization failed.
Please connect/cradle a real device or download the User-level Windows Mobile Device Center Application
from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?linkid=67763
```

Comparing the properties for the unit test and the application:

- Conditional compilation symbols are identical
- Platform target is identical ("Any CPU")
- Framework Version is identical (v3.5)
- Platform is identical ("Windows CE")
- Output file folder is identical
- Both have "Display the latest version of the .NET Compact Framework" checked
- Output type for the application is "Windows Application", for the unit test is "Class Library" but it seems like that's what it wants.

The error message seems to indicate the VS2008 can't connect to the emulator, but since the program is running I know that isn't the case.  Can I not run unit tests on an emulator?

Or am I missing files?  Is there something I need to install, in order to perform unit tests? Nowhere on my system do I have a file named Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes*.*.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the SmartDeviceTestRun.testrunConfig file, it was set to run on the actual device instead of the emulator.  This web site was helpful:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384146%28v=vs.90%29.aspx